# NSTableView hideRowsAtIndexes does not work on Sierra

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, macos-sierra

I have a NSTableView that needs to be refreshed, and some of its rows hidden after that. It is working on Mojave and Catalina, but it is not hiding rows on Sierra.

According to Apple documentation it should be supported from version macOS 10.11+.
[link to documentation for hideRowsAtIndexes](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nstableview/1534141-hiderowsatindexes?language=objc).

This is the block of code that is not working:

```
    [_tableView reloadData];
    [_tableView beginUpdates];
    [_tableView hideRowsAtIndexes:indexesOfRowsToHide withAnimation:NSTableViewAnimationEffectNone];
    [_tableView endUpdates];
```

Comment: Check if the delegate method `tableView:didRemoveRowView:forRow:` gets called. Otherwise, consider dropping macOS Sierra support? ^_^

Comment: See [NSTableView unhideRowsAtIndexes crashes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47843548/4244136)

Comment: @Willeke thanks for pointing to answer. It is described there that it is fixed in High Sierra.

Comment: Question is answered in [NSTableView unhideRowsAtIndexes crashes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37616958/nstableview-unhiderowsatindexes-crashes/47843548#47843548)