# Is hiding rows in NSTableView usable?

Tags: swift, macos, nstableview, appkit

I have an NSTableView which should only display a specific set of rows from an array of objects depending on selections made elsewhere.  To achieve this I filtered the array to create a new copy containing only those to display.

As I use an IndexSet to create the filtered copy I though I could instead just use the full Array of objects as the data source and instead use the `NSTableView.hideRows(at:withAnimation:)` and `.unhideRows(at:withAnimation:)` methods to control which are displayed.  But I have come across two issues and cannot see them documented anywhere.

Firstly, when calling `.unhideRows(at:)` when nothing is hidden the passed IndexSet is instead hidden.  This is completely counter-intuitive and not a documented behaviour on developer.apple.com.  It only occurs when no rows are hidden, calling the method any other time works as would be expected, that is by effectively performing an `.hiddenRowIndexes.subtract()` with the IndexSet provided.

Obviously this can be easily worked around by manually checking `NSTableView.hiddenRowIndexes.count` first and only calling the method if necessary.  But have I missed this being reported as a known bug anywhere?  Or that this behaviour is intentional?

```
print(myTableView.hiddenRowIndexes)
// prints: 0 indexes

let rows = IndexSet(arrayLiteral: 0,1,2,4,6)
myTableView.hideRows(at: rows)
print(myTableView.hiddenRowIndexes)
// prints: 5 indexes [0, 1, 2, 4, 6]

let moreRows = IndexSet(arrayLiteral: 3,7,9,10,11)
myTableView.hideRows(at: moreRows)
print(myTableView.hiddenRowIndexes)
// prints: 5 indexes [0, 1, 2, 4, 6]
```

The other problem makes the functionality unusable for me.  The Apple documentation says:

> Hidden table rows have a height of zero and cannot be selected by the user. However, if a selected table row is hidden, it will remain selected.

However this is not true as they can be selected.  Using a keyboard the up and arrow keys move the selection between every visible row, as would be expected.  But holding down SHIFT to extend a selection it will instead move the selection between every row, visible or not.  Similarly pressing CMD+A also selects every row, including ones that are hidden, and not just visible rows.

Though I do not use the `.selectRowIndexes(_:byExtendingSelection:)` method, I checked this and it also allows selecting hidden rows.

The only way to work around this issue is to observe `.selectedRowIndexes`, check whether any hidden rows has been selected, then replacing such a selection with the next visible row, then deselecting visible rows.  At this point it seems simpler to create the array copy as a data source.

Again, have I missed this being reported as a known bug anywhere?  The difference between using the arrow keys with and without SHIFT suggests it cannot be intentional.

Incidentally, I am aware of the bugs fixed in AppKit 10.13, one of which as noted and resolved in the question here: [NSTableView unhideRowsAtIndexes crashes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37616958/nstableview-unhiderowsatindexes-crashes).  But that just further makes me think this feature was badly written and cannot be relied on.

I am using Xcode 11.7 on macOS 10.14.6.

Comment: `NSTableView` is a mess. Don't hide rows or work around the bugs.

Comment: So I have not missed anything, it is just really that bad.  Thank you, I will just revert my changes and not hide rows.

Comment: The `- (NSIndexSet *)tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView 
selectionIndexesForProposedSelection:(NSIndexSet *)proposedSelectionIndexes;` allows you to customise proposed selection. Thus, the "selection" issue when using arrow navigation, SHIFT+selection, cmd+a, etc. is not a really issue ;)

Comment: @Vlad I never even thought to check for a delegate method like that, yet it seems a very AppKit way of doing things!  You should post is an answer so I can accept it.  Thank you.